# Is there any built-in MSMOTE

Tags: python, r

I am trying to deal with data imbalance within a small dataset. Just found an article talking about SMOTE and MSMOTE [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/#comment-126470)

It seems that MSMOTE can overcome the shortages of SMOTE, so I really want to try it. MSMOTE paper is published in 2009, however I could not find any library related to MSMOTE in R or python.

Do you know whether there is any built-in **MSMOTE** I could try? I'm fine with whatever programming language...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "imbalanced-learn" package in Python. 
This is the [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for future reference.

Here is a library with multiple variants to **SMOTE** in Python.

In particular, includes **MSMOTE**: https://smote-variants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oversamplers.html?highlight=msmote#msmote

```
oversampler= smote_variants.MSMOTE()
X_samp, y_samp= oversampler.sample(X, y)
```